# regular expression punctuation '

Tags: python, regex

We have a string:

```
application-label:'I'go Reader'
```

What regular expression should we write (in Python) to match:

```
I'go Reader
```

Note:
I tried:

```
re.search(r"(?<=label\=\')[\d\w\s\' ]+?(?=\')", text)
```

But it match the string until the first '. How to match until the substring before the second '?

Comment: At least try something first!

Comment: What did you try? Why do you expect us to solve this homework? What did you read about regular expressions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: Make the quantifier non-greedy (lazy). FYI, you don't have to escape the `'`.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://re-try.appspot.com/

Answer (score 3):

Just make the quantifier greedy so that it tries to find the longest match:

```
re.search(r"(?<=label\=\')[\d\w\s\' ]+(?=\')", text)
#                                    ^^
```

Whether this works for you or not depends on your input.

But if this the complete string or each input always follows the pattern `label:'content'`, I would just split at the first colon and remove the quotation marks:

```
content = text.split(':', 1)[1].strip("'")
```